# Is it possible to run two versions of Ubuntu side by side on a single Machine using wubi?

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable booting multiple Ubuntu Wubi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129149/how-to-enable-booting-multiple-ubuntu-wubi)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 installed using Wubi (OS: Windows 7 x64). Now Can I install 12.04 LTS on a different drive and use it side by side ?

I don't want to loose all the programs I have installed on Ubuntu 11.10 and moreover I feel I need more space on the Ubuntu portion. Being installed using Wubi it is not possible to increase the space normally. So now I think my options are either Install Ubuntu 12.04 on another Drive and reinstall all the softwares I had or Increase the Wubi partition.

Comment: Resize Wubi: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk

Comment: Have you considered not using wubi? There are procedures for migrating wubi installations to a separate EXT partition (see wubi help on ubuntu.com) and you can certainly multiple boot easily. All procedures for installation are potentially dangerous, so don't do anything without a full backup, and with wubi, the means to repair/re-install Windows if there is a problem.