# How to enable GRUB menu on Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: server, grub2, configuration

I have an Ubuntu server installed, and no matter what settings do I try to change, the GRUB menu won't appear. It only shows "Booting hard disk ...10... 9..." and that's all!

My [/etc/default/grub](http://pastebin.com/28RCjGxu) file.
The [/boot/grub/grub.cfg](http://pastebin.com/Bi5UbGwg).

**It's a KVM guest.**

Comment: How do I accept TWO answers? `izx` won the prize, his solution displays the menu always. `Cumulus` won the second prize, his solution shows the menu when you want to. Awesomeness. Ty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Here's the relevant portion of your pastebin'd `/etc/default/grub`:

  [image]
- Please comment out these lines in `/etc/default/grub` **by adding a `#` in front:**

  ```
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
  ```
- Save, and then run `sudo update-grub`
- The menu should now appear on every run, with a 10 second timeout for the default entry (0); we just "un-hid" the menu during the timeout countdown.

Comment: As you can tell from his pastebin, this has already been done.

Comment: @Cumulus007: you are wrong. See added image in edit.

Answer (score 5):

Try holding the shift key during boot. Sometimes you need to repeatedly keep tapping the key (up/down, up/down, etc.) instead of just holding it down to get this to work.

Comment: But how do you keep holding the shift key via VNC? :)

Comment: Yepp!........ :)

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed. Shiki, I have no experience with KVM nor running it over VNC.

Comment: Holding shift worked for me when running 12.04 as a VirtualBox guest.

Comment: In my case, repeatedly tapping Shift was required.