# Wubi on Windows 10

Tags: wubi

..yes I managed that. It works just by some magic I suppose.

I would like to try something else now: multiple wubi installation side by side..

By this I would have multiple entries in BCD. But I need to know how the wubildr and wubildr.mbr are generated. I seem to have found the source for wubildr from grub-mkimage in lupin-support but cannot find where wubildr.mbr is generated. Can someone provide insight to that?

In particular, the wubildr that is shipped when Ubuntu is installed via the CD and not the pre-packaged disk image.

[edit]
To clarify, I think I would have to modify wubildr.mbr to search for a different wubildr.

Comment: I think you can do it via "bcdedit" in the Windows CMD. Do a bit of googling on bcdedit.

Comment: Just to let you know, wubi is not recommended. With that said, can't you just install another wubi installation in windows just like you did the first one? Although I have never done it, it seems like it should just do all that stuff for you automatically just like it did for the first wubi install. Have you tried installing a second wubi install within windows yet or does it try to replace your existing wubi?

Comment: "Magic" is a poor explanation in a technology related context. If you tell us what you actually did someone else can reproduce, evaluate and probably take the next step.

Comment: @AndroidDev You should give an example of the bcdedit command with the parameters you had in mind and why you think they would help solve the problem, otherwise your comment is just a non-constructive "let me google that for you" kind of comment.

Comment: You can't do this in BCDEDIT. Wubildr.mbr is dumb as a post and searches partitions until it finds the first wubildr file. You can add as many as you like to BCDEDIT and it will always load the same Wubi. What you need to do is modify the grub within the first Wubi install. That said, you cannot install more than one Wubi except manually (the installer removes the old one first).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable booting multiple Ubuntu Wubi?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129149/how-to-enable-booting-multiple-ubuntu-wubi)

Answer (score 3):

> To clarify, I think I would have to modify wubildr.mbr to search for a
>   different wubildr.

It is easy to create a wubildr.mbr which searches for a different wubildr. see [Makefile of Wubi](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/wubi/trunk/view/head:/Makefile)

```
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/grub-ntldr-img --grub2 --boot-file=wubildr -o build/winboot/wubildr.mbr
```

**/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/grub-ntldr-img** is part of the package **grub-pc-bin** and it is really easy to change parameters. e.g.:

```
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/grub-ntldr-img --grub2 --boot-file=xxxxldr -o xxxxldr.mbr
```

This creates a xxxxldr.mbr which searches for xxxxldr .

But note: xxxxldr.mbr works in legacy BIOS mode (non-UEFI mode) only and you need a xxxxldr with different configuration files. If you just copy wubildr to xxxxldr it loads the same Wubi installation.

> Wubi on Windows 10

If you intend to use Windows 10 in UEFI mode, better to use a customized GRUB2 loader for UEFI. see [Makefile of a Wubi for UEFI](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/blob/master/Makefile)

```
grub-mkimage -O x86_64-efi -c build/winboot/wubildr-bootstrap.cfg -m build/winboot/wubildr.tar -o build/winboot/EFI/grubx64.efi \
        loadenv part_msdos part_gpt fat ntfs ext2 ntfscomp iso9660 loopback search linux linuxefi boot minicmd cat cpuid chain halt help ls reboot \
        echo test configfile gzio normal sleep memdisk tar font gfxterm gettext true efi_gop efi_uga video_bochs video_cirrus probe efifwsetup \
        all_video gfxterm_background png gfxmenu
```

Comment: It seems to me though that `--grub2` is a no-op if `--boot-file` is also specified. All that `--grub2` [seems to do](https://github.com/chenall/grubutils/blob/master/grubutils/grubinst/grubinst.c#L2063) is to set the boot-file name to `G2LDR`, but that's then overridden by `--boot-file` (in how it's used in your answer).